# Does having to be an authenticated and authorized user to access a feature reduce or eliminate the risk and impact of a security vulnerability?

Tags: authentication, security, architecture, authorization, xxe

Hi I am currently working an effort to patch security vulnerabilities identified in CVEs that are introduced by third-party libs. Part of doing that is assessing the risk and impact of these vulnerabilities. The question is "Does having to be an authenticated and authorized user to access a feature reduce or eliminate the risk and impact of a security vulnerability?" Is it like saying something is behind a firewall, therefore it is secure? Especially if that user group is pretty controlled? I know it may sound like a dumb question, but I'm thinking a large part of hacking is obtaining credentials or pretending to be someone else, therefore you are still vulnerable.

The specific vulnerability I am looking at is XML External Entity Injection (XXE) attacks. Our app is not open to non-authenticated users.  So if you have to be given credentials to access the UI and services, can you assume that the limited group access works like a firewall and moves the risk and impact down significantly?  Does the XXE assessment of HIGH criticality move down to LOW or maybe even none then?

Comment: Only you can answer this question for your own case, considering your own threat model. Usually having to be authenticated reduces but does not eliminate the risk. Look at how scoring like CVSS works, if you fill your data in a CVSS calculator, you can use that as a basis for your seveirty decision (one question in CVSS is exactly the necessary privileges for an attacker).

Comment: Thank you.  I wasn't aware of the CVSS calculators.  Very helpful!